# A question on grammar

Tags: grammaticality

I am an English teacher—a non-native, of course. During teaching my coursebook, I came across a structure that seems to be wrong:

> His was lost at the dry cleaners.

Is it correct grammatically to write/say "his was lost"?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please edit your post to explain why you think this sentence would not be grammatical; otherwise, this question may be closed as proofreading. The sentence is unremarkable, if there is a bit of context. *Both Michael and I lost dinner jackets. His was lost at the dry cleaners. Mine was lost in the 1970s*.

Comment: Context is absolutely imperative. Yes, it is grammatically correct, *per se,* if the object lost is to be understood from the context.

Answer (score 2):

Not by itself, but as part of a phrase it would be acceptable. You could say something like:

> My suit was ready in time for the wedding, but his was lost at the dry cleaner's.

In this case, "his" is understood to mean "his suit."